# org.json.JSONException: Value <style of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

Tags: java, json

```
JSONObject jsonObject;
try {
    int ch;
    StringBuffer b = new StringBuffer();
    System.out.println("Before second while loop");
    while((ch=is.read())!= -1) {
        b.append((char) ch);
    }
    jsonObject = new JSONObject(b.toString());
    String statusStr =  jsonObject.getString("status");
    String responseCode = jsonObject.getString("responseCode");
    Log.e("","JSON STATUS"+statusStr);
    Log.e("","JSON RESPONSE"+responseCode);
```

I am getting error org.json.JSONException: Value  at

```
jsonObject = new JSONObject(b.toString());
```

Comment: it would be helpful if you post a sample of you JSON string, and the rest of the code is useless with exception of the lines you are performing `getString` (just to know your intention)

Comment: Make System.err.println(b.toString()) and show output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your string in `new JSONObject(String)` should be in braces. Begin from `{` and end with `}`

Also you should have JSON formatted text in your string, like in example

```
{"person": {"id": "1", "firstName": "first", "lastName": "last", "middleName": "middle"}, "key" : "value" }
```

Comment: the closing '}' is for the while loop, not the try block

Comment: I said about String in constructor new JSONObject(String), not about brackets in code

Comment: this string should "Begin from { and end with }"

Comment: OH, sorry, didn't catch your meaning :)

Comment: @onkar please post a sample of json you are using

Comment: JSONObject jsonObject;
   try {

    int ch;
    StringBuffer b = new StringBuffer();
    System.out.println("Before second while loop");
    while ((ch = is.read()) != -1) {

     b.append((char) ch);

    }

    System.out.println("the response is "+b.toString());
    jsonObject = new JSONObject(b.toString());


    String statusStr =  jsonObject.getString("status");
    String responseCode = jsonObject.getString("responseCode");

Comment: the JSON notation... the one you are retrieving from `is`

Comment: InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();

Comment: Thank you guys issue has been solved. The error was from serverside...  it was not reacting as expected